# Prioritizing resolvers in SBT build file

Tags: scala, sbt

I was wondering if there is a easier way to prioritize resolvers in `build.sbt` file.

**Background:**

I have a jar that is published to maven central repository which is fetched every time I try to build my project. Now while active development I would like this jar to be fetched from local repository (~/.ivy/local) instead but it was still getting fetched from the public maven repository. What I have tried is that I have created a `~/.sbt/repositories` file as shown below and start SBT with `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true` vm args (as explained [sbt proxy repository docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html#sbt+Configuration)).

**~/.sbt/repositories**

```
[repositories]
  local
  maven-central
  sbt-releases-repo: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  sbt-plugins-repo: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.raphtory" %% "core" % "0.1.0")
```

[See this](https://github.com/iamsmkr/til/blob/master/sbt.md#making-sbt-fetch-locally-published-jars-instead-of-reaching-out-to-public-maven-repositories)

I know ideally we should be creating newer unpublished version to work with like `SNAPSHOT` version and that works fine but it still begs the question why SBT is not prioritizing locally published `publishLocal` jar over the one available on maven? Also is there any easier way to achieve this by making a small change right in the `build.sbt` file?

Comment: Do you have any evidence it first check the remote repos? I've always observed it check first the local repo.

Comment: @GaëlJ Yes, the one published in maven is outdated one, the latest version has breaking changes! That's how I know its always picking up from the public repo.

Comment: I mean, can you show the logs of SBT when it tries to download the dependency?